# Intercept cloud firestore write operations for complex business logic

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to implement some complex business logic server-side to prevent internal conflicts between my Firestore documents. In particular I'd like to prevent double-bookings in a calendar.

I've been looking into cloud Firestore functions as a means to an end. However, all write operation events seems to be triggered *after the fact*, and as such the relevant business logic will not be invoked after the damage is done.

So far I have only discovered one pattern to circumvent this, and that is by using an indirection collection like so:

1. Write operation to 'temporary_calendar'-collection
2. onWrite for 'temporary_calendar'-collection is triggered
3. Check if newly minted temporary calendar item conflicts with existing 'calendar'-collection item
4. If not, write temporary item to 'calendar'-collection

Is this the standard way of implementing this? And if so, what would be a good way to communicate the conflict back to the originating client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is **a** common way of implementing content moderation. The unprivileged user writes to a pending queue, where a privileged process then picks the content up and checks its validity. If the content is valid, the privileged process writes it to its final location. If the content is not valid, it rejects the content. And in either way, it writes a response for the client in yet another location int he database, with a key that the user know (typically the same ID as the client used when writing the request).

So you have three collections:

1. The `calendar`, which has the actual calendar items.
2. The `requests`, which is where the clients write their requests. You'll typically make this a write-only collection, where all users can write, but nobody (but the privileged process) can read.
3. The `responses`, which is where the privileged process writes its responses and the the client reads it from. So this is a read-only location, where only the privileged process can write.

The documents in `requests` and `responses` use the same ID, so that the client can write its request and then monitor for a response to that specific request.

Comment: Thank you for your input Frank! I was stuck in a more classical REST-API mind-set, with validity checks as a middleware component before hitting the db.

Comment: That's also an option, and in that scenario you'd call a Cloud Function directly from your code. But that'd mean that the app completely stops working when the user is offline, which we'd typically like to prevent is possible. If